# PHP preg_split regex does not split with dot

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I'm using the following regex to split a string to an array. Everything goes fine but for some reason it does not the splitting with `\.(space)`. How would i need to change it to make it work?

```
  $sentences  = preg_split(" / (\. |, and|, or|, but|, nor|, so|, for|, yet|after|although|as|as if|as long as|because|before|even if|even though|if|once|provided|since|so that|that|though|till|unless|until|what|when|whenever|wherever|whether|while) /",$sentences);
```

Comment: Do you really want to match (space)(dot)(space)?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I want to match (dot)(space)

Comment: @bicycle no `/ (\. |,` always expects a prefixed space `\s.\s`. `/(\. |,` will fix it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your whitespace is the issue here. Regular expressions take this into account, so change it to this:

```
$sentences = preg_split("/(\. |, and|, or|, but|, nor|, so|, for|, yet|after|although|as|as if|as long as|because|before|even if|even though|if|once|provided|since|so that|that|though|till|unless|until|what|when|whenever|wherever|whether|while)/",$sentences);
```

Note how the whitespace after the first `/` and before the final `/` have been removed.

Comment: @Allendar I can't yet, there is a minimum delay before you can accept :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using double quotes, you have to double escape the dot, so `\\.` instead of just `\.`

Comment: This just isn't true! Double escaping is only needed for an actual backslash character.

Comment: @JonathanCairns you *do want* an actual backslash in that case

Comment: May have misunderstood: @bicycle do you want to split on a literal `\.`?

Comment: Escaped slashing is meant for the element you are escaping. If you want to escape `\` for example in PHP you need `\\\\` to escape RegEx's confusion two times and escape the string-lash two times. `\\.` will match `\\` followed by one alpha-numeric characters.

Comment: Oops the StackOverflow tags even missed the escapes :P. I mean \\\\ to escape the backward slash and that \\. will match "\" followed by any alpha-numerical character.

Comment: @JonathanCairns to split on literal `\.` you should use `"\\\\."`

Comment: @JonathanCairns Yeah true and a space behind it also. In fact it has to split a text into smaller sentences. A period is always trailed with a space.

Comment: It looks like @bicycle was trying to split on a `.` character, and correctly backslashed the regex dot to mean a literal `.` (rather than any character as it means in regex).

Comment: @JonathanCairns Yeah that's true indeed as may look logical looking at the other regex match cases as well hahaha

Comment: @JonathanCairns The main issue here was not the backslash, it was the spaces, as you pointed out in your answer. Btw if you're using double quoted strings you should escape backslash.